# Обратиться к дочернему элементу html при клике по самому элементу

Tags: javascript, html, события

Есть иконка поверх кнопки:

```
<button data-type="lock">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-lock-open"></i>
</button>
```

Вопрос: как обратиться к иконке, даже если клик был по самой кнопке (между иконкой м границей кнопки)?
В обученмм предлагается так:

```
const node = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'i'
        ? event.target
        : event.target.children[0]
```

Проблема в том, что даже в образце срабатывает только случай "event.target.children[0]".
Подскажите, как решить или как нагуглить развернутое поясненме

Comment: "*Есть иконка поверх кнопки:*"  --- нет, тут иконка **внутри кнопки**

Comment: "*даже если клик был по самой кнопке*" ---  повесить клик на саму кнопку. а не на иконку.

Comment: `button.addEventListener("click", (event) => { button.querySelector("i").dispatchEvent(event) });` - решение. Глупое, но решение. Почему глупое? Потому что события в js и так распространяются по дереву, надо использовать эту особенность чтобы правильно решить такие задачи. Но как использовать зависит уже от задачи.